# Moving 2 divs of different height independently of each other on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Lets say i have 2 divs one is used for menu (left div) and the other (right div) for the contents. 
Contents are listviews with many list items . (generated as you scroll down)
Left menu is also a listview with flexible no of list items ( may or may not require scroll)
I wish to scroll on left div w/o moving the page ( or to say right div shouldn't move)

For example the facbook mobile settings --click present a left menu which can be scrolled w/o scrolling the page.

I hope i've made myself clear enough.

I am using jquery mobile poppup and positioning it to left and top edges of the page.
Slide the 2nd (right div) to right by the width of the left div.
touch on right div makes left div disappear and slides back it to (left 0 px).

Answer (score 2):

Why not fix the height of the left div and set `overflow:scroll` css property which enables you to scroll ? this will not scroll the whole page.

**EDIT**
the other options available for you is to use

`overflow:auto` which generate scroll bar only when there is a content, nice catch by a fellow Stackoverflow friend

`overflow-y` if you want to scroll only the vertical way

`overflow-x` if you want to scroll only the horizontal way

Comment: You're on the right track, but I'd suggest using `overflow: auto` instead. That way, when there's not enough contents in the div to require scrolling, you won't see a scroll bar. `overflow: scroll` will show a scroll bar no matter what, which can be ugly. In fact, I'd do `overflow-y: auto` so there's no chance of a horizontal scroll bar appearing.

Comment: on mobile i don't think it will show a regular scroll bar, it shows some kind of tiny scroll bar, which will be visible only if you scroll. being more precise "Auto" will generate a scroll bar only if there is a content, Scroll will always generate a scroll bar(on mobile it is in a tiny scrollbar shape)

Comment: and an up for your answer. :)